# Makefile to build several files in different folders

Tags: makefile, msp430

I have been trying to use MSP GCC compiler. I have written a makefile for single file and able to compile and flash in the MSP430 device.

I don't know how to write makefile for many source files in different folder inter dependent with each other.

I am developing a serial deriver
folder and file structure is as follows

```
serial_driver/App
serial_driver/App/inc/app.h
serial_driver/App/inc/app.c
serial_driver/controller
serial_driver/controller/inc/hardware.h
serial_driver/controller/inc/globaldef.h
serial_driver/controller/src/ctrl.c
serial_driver/UART
serial_driver/UART/inc/uart.h
serial_driver/UART/src/uart.c
```

Can any give some ideas to write make files for this project and how to expand in future bigger projects.

Thanks and Regards
Ashok Kumar P

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add makefile in each directory and from the parent makefile you can call each makefile with -C option.

for eg:

in `App` directory you can have your makefile and from the makefile in `serial_driver`

you can have a statememt

```
make -C ./App
```

this statement will execute the makefile in App directory

Similarly you can call all the makefiles in the sub directories in this manner.

Comment: files in App dirrectory is depend with files in other directories. how to link all the files.

Answer (score 0):

What I use is `rake` (Ruby make) instead of `make` (I HATE `make`, it's so frustrating and debugs like crap)

I have a sample rake system [here](http://github.com/sergiocampama/Launchpad), where I have small projects inside my workspace. Each project's `Rakefile` references a `Rakefile.include` file on the same level as the project folders, where all the magic happens. It's pretty well documented if you want to take a look at it. It's customized for the Launchpad, but can be changed to anything. There's also a complete guide to install the latest version of mspgcc.

The cool thing is that you can do

```
rake mcu=msp430g2553
rake install
```

And it will compile all the source files in your project (including subfolders and sub-subfolders and so on) for that specific version of the msp430, and install it on the Launchpad. (Installation on the Launchpad is done with `mspdebug`)